# How to select data in 2 month(from now) use postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to sql and database work .  Now I want select data in 2 month from now . the key is xxdate lookslike `2019-4-11`

like: 
`select * from table where date > now() - 2 month`

but I don't know the correct way to express it. can someone help?

Comment: Which data type is `date`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date > (current_date - interval '2 month')::date;
```